# Python Selenium | Update Proxy Without Restarting Browser

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

I am creating a bot that goes to a website, changes proxy, and then reloads the website. I want the update the proxy for the chrome webdriver in the loop, but I only found a way to do it if I create a new webdriver with a new proxy. I only want to update the current chromedriver's proxy, not create a new one with a new proxy.

```
x = 1
while x < 5:

    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % random.choice(PROXY))

    chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    chrome.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")
    x = x + 1
```

This code creates a new webdriver every time it cycles through the loop. How can I make it so it only updates a new proxy to the current webdriver instead?

The reason for me wanting to change proxy without restarting the browser is because if I restart I'll need to type the captcha while when I don't, I can simply change proxy and hit send without typing in the captcha.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, it only work for PhantomJS

```
    browser.command_executor._commands['executePhantomScript'] = ('POST', '/session/$sessionId/phantom/execute')
    browser.execute('executePhantomScript', {'script': 'phantom.setProxy('PROXY_IP', 'PROXY_PORT');', 'args' : [] })
```

Pass proxy via argument doesnt allow to change proxy on run time. You will have to make another instance of the webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firefox geckodriver you can use this code

```
driver = = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=proxy_settings, executable_path='geckodriver')

driver.refresh()
```

Refresh allows new proxy to take effect/ doesnt work with chrome